# Eclipsify not working for Play v1.2.5

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am able to create the new app successfully in Play Framework v1.2.5 but not able to eclipsify the newly created project.

The name of the project is `firstApp`, it is created in `F:\PlayWOrkspace`.

Hence now the directory structure is: `F:\PlayWOrkspace\firstApp`. The firstAPp directory contains all the sub folders such as app, conf, etc etc.

I tried running the eclipsify command in command prompt after creating the new project but i am getting an error message in command prompt telling:

`The  command is not recognized...`

Please let me know how to run the eclipsify command.... :(

Regards,

Comment: Did you run `eclipsify` or `play eclipsify`?

Comment: what command did you run with what parameters?

Comment: It is very likely that the command you try to eclipsify your project is incorrect. It should be `directory_of_play\play eclipsify directory_of_project` if you don' t have play directory in your path environment variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
play eclipsify firstApp
```

from the `F:\PlayWOrkspace` directory

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the short version (less likely to miss-spell):  `play ec` (if you are in `F:\PlayWOrkspace\firstApp`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really helpful. 1 more thing: when I run the app in command prompt, it displays the port number used. How to `stop the server` with a short cut in command prompt?

Comment: you can use `play stop` but if you use `play run` instead of `play start` you can just CTRL+C in the window to kill it.